# How to install Windows 10 alongside with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, system-installation, dual-boot

I have a Ubuntu on my computer. Due to my work, I need a Windows 10 machine. How can I make a dual boot machine? I think a normal Windows installation removes Ubuntu. So can I make some partition first where I install Windows? And how can I make a Windows 10 bootable USB on Ubuntu?

Comment: What have you tried so far? In general it's far easier to start with window$ and install linux side by side, but I've done both successfully.

Comment: I tried to use Woeusb but the button "Install" is disabled so I can't use it. I have downloaded the Windows 10 iso file to my computer.

Comment: You have to have Windows fast start up off, and have to update UEFI & SSD firmware. If Optane/Intel RST change to AHCI, but install AHCI driver into Windows first. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  Be sure to create installer in UEFI boot mode, not old BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode.

Answer (score 1):

Consider installing MS-Windows in Virtual-Box. That way you can run both at the same time.

Performance may be low for 3D programs in the MS-Windows (Games, CAD, etc), but other than that it is fine. So long as you have a reasonably modern CPU, and descent amount of RAM.